# Proguard error (Xamarin c#)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I writing Android app.

When i set Release mode and run it, have this.

```
java.exe exited with code 1
```

Java Heap size is set to 1G

Output has this

```
    1>PROGUARD : warning : com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.HttpUrlDownloader$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
1>PROGUARD : warning : com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.HttpUrlDownloader$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
1>PROGUARD : warning : com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.HttpUrlDownloader$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
1>PROGUARD : warning : com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.HttpUrlDownloader$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
1>PROGUARD : warning : com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.HttpUrlDownloader$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
1>PROGUARD : warning : com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.UrlImageViewHelper$RequestPropertiesCallback: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
1>PROGUARD : warning : okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
1>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
1>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
1>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
1>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
1>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
1>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
1>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
1>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
1>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
1>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
1>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
1>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
1>PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
1>PROGUARD : warning : there were 20 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thank's